# How to change the files in my original commit

Tags: git, rebase

Background: I'm trying to remove all `bin`, `obj`, and `packages` folders, and all files with the pattern `*.suo`, `*.user` and `_.ReSharper.*` from my history.

I first checked out master and ran

```
git rebase -i --root $tip
```

then in the edit window I changed the first commit from `pick` to `edit` and hit `Esc` + `:wp`.

Then I added a `.gitignore` files with

```
*.suo
*.user
_ReSharper.*
bin/
obj/
packages/
```

Then, I did a `git log` to check that my first commit was the only one in the log. Good so far.

Then, I went to Amend Last Commit using Tortoise and it said "no files were changed or added since your last commit." I expected to see all the files that were in my first commit. Why don't I see them?

Comment: '.gitignore' is for files that you don't want to commit but once it's committed, it has no effect (behaviour expected!) . You should uncommit them if you need it. Things apart, perhaps you should have a look to http://gitignore.io instead of doing your entirely yourself...

Answer (score 0):

If the files were already committed on previous revisions, just adding the files to .gitignore won't change anything. That is telling git to ignore those files if they show up as "new" files. Files already committed, git will continue tracking them and reporting if they change. If you want to get rid of them on previous revisions, you will either have to amend those revisions or pull the big guns with `git filter-branch`. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch